# Como ler um JSON no Harbour?

Tags: json, harbour

No PHP, para interpretar um arquivo JSON para a linguagem, podemos usar a função `json_decode`. Já no Javascript, podemos usar `JSON.parse`.

E no Harbour? Existe alguma função para interpretar o JSON?

Exemplo:

```
Procedure Main()
   LOCAL json := '{"nome": "Wallace"}'
   ? json
   Return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Decodificando com `hb_JsonDecode`

O Harbour já tem função nativa para isto:

```
hHash := hb_JsonDecode( cJson )
```

Exemplo:

```
hData := hb_JsonDecode( '{"Wallace":"Maxters","Score":100000}' )
? hData['Wallace']
```

Resultado:

```
Maxters
```

### Codificando com `hb_JsonEncode`

```
cJson := hb_JsonEncode( xData )
```

Exemplo:

```
? hb_JsonEncode( {'teste' => 123} )
```

Resultado:

```
{"teste":123}
```

Ainda, tem opção de resultado formatado:

```
hb_jsonEncode( xValue [, lHuman = .F. | nIndent = 0 ] ) --> cJSON
```

o segundo parâmetro pode ser .T. para tabulação, ou numérico para indentar com espaços

### Implementação:

- https://github.com/harbour/core/blob/master/src/rtl/hbjson.c